# Will creating more pages around keywords for which we are already ranking help SEO or hurt?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking, content, page

I have researched this but got mixed and confusing information.

We are trying to rank our India based company which provides the following services:

- Engineering Design Services
- Architectural Design Services
- MEP Design Services

our target audiences are in the US and UK.

Offcource, we are targetting above services keywords on most of our main pages and created dedicated services pages too. But lately, we found out that we are ranking well for keywords like Outsourcing Engineering Design Services, Outsourcing Architectural Design Services, etc... which are actually very very good keywords in terms of closing the leads/ inquiries as people are actually looking out for outsourcing but the search count for those keywords is low. (though we closed 2 inquiries from those keywords). These pages we created just to increase the content of the website.

I really want to give it a try to target those keywords by creating more pages, blog posts, backlinks, etc...

My question is if we create more and more pages around those keywords then will it affect the rankings of the pages which are already ranking for those keywords or will the new pages compete against those pages or the new pages will help to boost current pages?

We can write good content and blog posts on the outsourcing topic but not sure if we should create new pages or increase the length of the existing pages.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create one page dedicated to all the outsourcing services. Let's call that page "outsourcing landing page".

Depending on the size of the information you want to provide for each different outsourcing  service, you might create separate pages for each and link them to the "outsourcing landing page" or have all the different information for each type of outsourcing service appear on the "outsourcing landing page". The second approach (if feasible size-wise) would be better in my opinion since all the different keywords will "team up" for ranking your "outsourcing landing page".

In any case, each "service" page should have links to its corresponding "outsourcing" page (or its corresponding "outsourcing" section of the "outsourcing landing page") and vice versa.

I like the approach of each page being in depth about a specific topic, so personally I would suggest creating new pages instead of expanding the ones you already have, all the more if you plan on providing a lot of information about the outsourcing process / logistics. Expanding your content pages too much will create an unpleasant user experience (especially for mobile users), whereas separating your content but keeping it tied together with internal links will create a more coherent experience.